# Android - communication with Laravel API

Tags: android, laravel

I'm writing an Android app that communicates with a Laravel API using JSON calls. It should also support register and login. I've been searching for some tutorial/example on how to do this, but the only one I found is this one: https://github.com/ProgrammationAndroid/Laravel-Passport-Android

But the video is french and it's also slightly outdated. I'm pretty sure there must be plenty of tutorials/examples on how to do this but it just can't find them. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction? I don't need to write the API itself, only calling the API from an Android client.

Comment: Did you even google it? I found this on the first search https://medium.com/modulr/create-api-authentication-with-passport-of-laravel-5-6-1dc2d400a7f. Also check laracast and/or codecourse for en tutorials.

Comment: I found that one, but that is about writing the API, as I said I don't need to write the API, I need to call the API from Android. And this page doesn't even contain the word "android".

Answer (score 0):

### [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport) / [OAuth 2.0](https://oauth.net/2/)

Laravel makes API authentication a breeze using Laravel Passport, which provides a full OAuth2 server implementation.

---

### [Grants](https://alexbilbie.com/guide-to-oauth-2-grants/)

The [OAuth 2.0 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) is a flexibile authorization framework that describes a number of grants (“methods”) for a client application to acquire an access token (which represents a user’s permission for the client to access their data) which can be used to authenticate a request to an API endpoint.

1. Authorization code grant
2. Implicit grant
3. Resource owner credentials grant
4. Client credentials grant
5. Password grant
6. Refresh token grant

> **Which OAuth 2.0 grant should I use?**
>
> A grant is a method of acquiring an access token. Deciding which grants to implement depends on the type of client the end user will be using, and the experience you want for your users.

[image: Grants]

---

### Implementation (1st party / Native app / Password grant)

#### Create an application

Passport will prompt you for more information about your client and will provide you with a client ID and secret :

```
php artisan passport:client --password
```

#### Requesting tokens

```
# http://laravel-app.tld/oauth/token
[
    'grant_type'    => 'password'         # Grant type
    'client_id'     => 'client-id'        # Application client ID
    'client_secret' => 'client-secret'    # Application client secret
    'username'      => 'email@domain.tld' # Form request
    'password'      => 's3cr3T'           # Form request
    'scope'         => '*'                # Scopes
]
```

Comment: I don't need to write the API itself. I'm looking for information on how to connect to it from Android. I know what the JSON needs to look like but I'm looking for examples on how to implement this in Android.

Comment: @0ne_Up my answer is not to create an API, but a way to connect your API with Andoroid by using OAuth. Didn't you read it?

Comment: partially, but I don't see anything about Android, just stuff about OAuth in general. Maybe I should be searching for "android oauth" and [this](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate) is the stuff I should be reading?

Comment: You need to learn more about difference between OAuth & API, before you asking it.